# Add a Column in Query

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank_id, name, SUM(points) AS points
  FROM battle_points
  WHERE category =  'test'
  AND user_id !=0
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY points DESC;
```

I'd like to add a column `rank` based on the total points. With this query, the points are fine but the `rank_id` virtual column doesn't match up.

For example, the top user with the most points has `rank` `26`, yet the `rank_id` column has a value of `24`.

How do I matchup the `rank_id` column with the points column?

Note: while I am fully versed in PHP, I need a solution for MySQL only.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, but you need to put the main query in a subquery so that the ordering occurs before the rank calculation, like so:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank_id, mainQ.* 
FROM (
   SELECT name, SUM(points) AS points
   FROM battle_points
   WHERE category =  'test'
      AND user_id !=0
   GROUP BY user_id
   ORDER BY points DESC
) AS mainQ
;
```

Edit: Qualified `*` to `mainQ.*`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your query but I'm getting an error before FROM. Your code looks good so I don't know where the error can be. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I have a typo/oversight, the source of the `*` needs specified, see edit.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! You saved me, thanks a lot.